# Custom Shape to PopupWindow

Tags: android

How to implement `PopupWindow` shape like on the screenshot below ?

I understand how to create `Rectangle` shape with stroke/solid color.

I know how to play with corners, but how can I implement an arrow `<` near `Close` label ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="@dimen/edittext_border"
        android:left="@dimen/edittext_border"
        android:right="@dimen/edittext_border"
        android:top="@dimen/edittext_border">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/edittext_border_width"
                android:color="@color/divider_color_light" />

            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <padding android:bottom="@dimen/awsome_edittext_padding" android:left="@dimen/awsome_edittext_padding" android:right="@dimen/awsome_edittext_padding"/>

        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

[image]

Comment: read about `nine patch drawable`s

Answer (score 0):

U can use .9 patch png as background for PopupWindow.

[image]
like below code `

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/popupbg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/POPUPBACkGROUND" >
</FrameLayout>
```

You can refer this [site!](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Menus-and-Popups)

Answer (score 0):

you can set exactly that type of background in custom popup
  see this library
     https://github.com/kvirair/Quick-Action